# How to approximate the sum of logarithms in terms of O(1/n)

Tags: number-theory

To show:$\sum _{m\leq n}\log m= n(\log n-1)+\dfrac{1}{2}\log n+c+O(1/n); m,n\in \mathbb{N}$ for some constant $c$

Using partial summation formula  and Riemann Stieljies I have been able to get $\sum _{m\leq n}\log m= n(\log n-1)+ \int _1^n(\{u\}/u) du$ and added and subtracted $\log x/2$ and landed in the integral $\int _1^n\dfrac{(\{u\}-\dfrac{1}{2})}{u} du$ but  how to estimate this and get $O(1/n)+c$  ?

Comment: Write $\int_1^n = \int_1^{\infty} - \int_n^{\infty}$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that by Stirling's approximation we have:

\begin{align}
\sqrt{2\pi}n^{n+\tfrac{1}{2}}e^{-n}e^{\tfrac{1}{12n+1}} \leq n! \leq \sqrt{2\pi}n^{n+\tfrac{1}{2}}e^{-n}e^{\tfrac{1}{12n+1}}. 
\end{align}

The natural logarithm of $n!$ can then be written as:

\begin{align}
\log(n!) = \tfrac{1}{2}\log(2\pi)+(n + \tfrac{1}{2})\log(n) - n + \lambda_n,
\end{align}

where $\tfrac{1}{12n+1} \leq \lambda_n \leq \tfrac{1}{12n}$ and thus $\lambda_n = O(\tfrac{1}{n})$. This helps you out because

\begin{align}
\sum_{m=1}^{n}\log(m) &= \log(\prod_{m=1}^{n}m) = \log(n!) \\
&= \tfrac{1}{2}\log(2\pi)+ n\log(n) + \tfrac{1}{2}\log(n) - n + O(\tfrac{1}{n}) \\
&=  n(\log(n) - 1) + \tfrac{1}{2})\log(n) + c + O(\tfrac{1}{n}).
\end{align}

With $c = \tfrac{1}{2}\log(n)$.